# How to consolidate if / elif statements in Python

Tags: if-statement, arguments

I looked around and did some research, but for some reason I still couldn't get it to work as planned. Basically, as a beginner, I wrote a Mastermind code game- same rules and all. Here's the code:

```
import random
trial = 0
def geuss():
    geuss = raw_input("What is your geuss? ")
    global g1
    global g2
    global g3
    global g4
    a = geuss[:-3]
    b = geuss[1:-2]
    c = geuss[2:-1]
    d = geuss[3:]
    if a == peg1:
        g1 = 'R'
    elif a == peg2:
        g1 = 'W'
    elif a == peg3:
        g1 = 'W'
    elif a == peg4:
        g1 = 'W'
    else:
        g1 = 'X'

    if b == peg2:
        g2 = 'R'
    elif b == peg1:
        g2 = 'W'
    elif b == peg3:
        g2 = 'W'
    elif b == peg4:
        g2 = 'W'
    else:
        g2 = 'X'

    if c == peg3:
        g3 = 'R'
    elif c == peg1:
        g3 = 'W'
    elif c == peg2:
        g3 = 'W'
    elif c == peg4:
        g3 = 'W'
    else:
        g3 = 'X'

    if d == peg4:
        g4 = 'R'
    elif d == peg1:
        g4 = 'W'
    elif d == peg2:
        g4 = 'W'
    elif d == peg3:
        g4 = 'W'
    else:
        g4 = 'X'

    print g1, g2, g3, g4
    global trial
    trial = trial + 1
    return trial



colour = ['B', 'G', 'Y', 'P', 'R']

peg1 = random.choice(colour)
peg2 = random.choice(colour)
peg3 = random.choice(colour)
peg4 = random.choice(colour)
g1 = 0
g2 = 0
g3 = 0
g4 = 0

print ""
while g1 != 'R' or g2 != 'R' or g3 != 'R' or g4 != 'R':
    geuss()
print "Congratulations! It took you %d tries to crack the code!" % trial

print ""
print "The code was %s%s%s%s." % (peg1, peg2, peg3, peg4)
```

As you can see the if and elif statements in the function 'geuss()' are needlessly wrong- but when I tried putting them together the script would always put a W.

```
    if a == peg1:
        g1 = 'R'
    elif a == peg2 or peg 3 or peg4:
        g1 = 'W'
    else:
        g1 = 'X'
```

Even when I put "QWER" in as an input, I would get an X. Is there some way I can consolidate them while still getting the correct response?

Also, off topic, if there are any other suggestions you can give me on the script as I am a beginner, that would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `or` or `and`, you need to specify which operation you are using. Here is what you wrote...

```
if a == peg1:
  g1 = 'R'
elif a == peg2 or peg 3 or peg4:
  g1 = 'W'
else:
  g1 = 'X'
```

The `elif` in that asks if `a` is equal to `peg2`, and then if peg3 or peg4 exists. You need to change it so `a == peg3/4` also. Like this...

```
elif a == peg2 or a == peg3 or a == peg4:
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your if/elif question a typical Python idiom to use a dictionary for a switch statement.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374239/why-doesnt-python-have-a-switch-statement
{'option1': function1,
 'option2': function2,
 'option3': function3,
 'option4': function4,
}.get(value, defaultfunction)()
```

However, in this case I believe you are taking the wrong approach. "Thinking" in Python is a little different than other languages and takes awhile to get used to doing things "the Python way". You seem to understand lists, and string slices which is good. You can leverage that a bit more to simplify your Mastermind program as shown below.

```
import random

trial = 0
colour = ['B', 'G', 'Y', 'P', 'R']

pegs = [random.choice(colour), random.choice(colour), random.choice(colour), random.choice(colour)]
guess_pegs = ['?', '?', '?', '?']

def main():
    print "Generating a code"
    print pegs

    guess()    
    print "Congratulations! It took you %d tries to crack the code!\n" % trial
    print "The code was: " + ', '.join(pegs) 

def guess():
    global trial
    global pegs
    global guess_pegs

    entry_list = ['?', '?', '?', '?']

    while pegs != guess_pegs :
        entry_list = raw_input("What is your guess? ").split(' ')

        trial = trial + 1

        if len(pegs) == len(entry_list) :
            for i in range(0,4) :
                if(entry_list[i] == pegs[i]) :
                    guess_pegs[i] = entry_list[i]
        print guess_pegs                    
        guess()

# Kick things off
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

An experienced python programmer would write:-

```
elif a == peg2 or a == peg3 or a == peg4:
```

as:-

```
elif a in (peg2, peg3, peg4):
```