# How to Consolidate if statements in Python for Text replacement

Tags: python

I have the following code I wrote in python, but I want to make it easier to maintain.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from docx import document


def replace_text(file_path, b1o, b1a, b1p, b1e):
  document = document(file_path)
   for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if 'B1O' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('B1O', b1o)
    if 'B1A' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('B1A', b1a)
    if 'B1P' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('B1P', b1p)
    if 'B1E' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('B1E', b1e)
return document
```

How can I combine the if statements and make them easier to manage?

I've looked at [How to consolidate if / elif statements in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721983/how-to-consolidate-if-elif-statements-in-python), but I'm unsure how to utilize the solution with this particular use case.

Thanks for any input!

EDIT: Here is the rest of the program snipped to include only the parts mentioned here.

```
def generate_file():
    # Open a file dialog to select a template file
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Select a template file",
        filetypes=[("Word files", "*.docx")],
        initialdir=r"C://desktop/Templates"
    )

# Get user input for variables
    b1o = input("Enter the name of the owner: ")
    b1a = input("Enter the address: ")
    b1p = input("Enter the phone number: ")
    b1e = input("Enter the email address: ")

# Replace placeholders with user input
    document = replace_text(file_path, b1o, b1a, b1p, b1e)

# Open a file dialog to select a folder to save the new file
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select a folder to save the new file")
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0] + "_" + b1p + "_" + b1o + ".docx"
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)

# Save the modified document as a new file
    document.save(file_path)
    print("File saved at:", file_path)

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Generate New Document")

# Create a button to generate a new file
    generate_button = Button(root, text="Select Template and 
    Generate", command=generate_file)
    generate_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you considered doing the replace calls unconditionally? Right now you're doing a scan for the `in` check plus another scan for the `replace()`. And think about a loop; f/e, `for (sigil, replacement) in (('B10', b1o), ('B1A', b1a), ...): paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(sigil, replacement)`

Comment: I don't understand what that means - let me look it up rq!

Comment: I just meant "unconditionally" with its usual English meaning: doing the replace without making a successful `in` check a condition of doing so.

Comment: that said, it'd be even better to use `re.sub()` to scan for _all four_ possible replacement fields at once and replace them at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient fix might look something like:

```
import re
import functools

def replace_text(file_path, b1o, b1a, b1p, b1e):
    document = document(file_path)
    replacements = { 'B1O': b1o, 'B1A': b1a, 'B1P': b1p, 'B1E': b1e }
    subFn = functools.partial(
      re.sub,
      '|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in replacements.keys()),
      lambda match: replacements[match.group(0)]
    )
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        paragraph.text = subFn(paragraph.text)
    return document
```

Using `re.sub()` lets us search for all four strings in a single pass, instead of needing to search for them one after the other.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'll include the MRE - let me smash apart the code and get you a working example

Comment: Updated with MRE

Comment: @Devon FWIW, I'd consider it a better reproducer if instead of adding more logic, you _ripped out_ the docx-aware bits to simplify to code that people with no Microsoft tools / Microsoft-compatible-tools can run. Also, that way, there's no need to include a docx input file to test with; can just hardcode an input string. Similarly, hardcode an input string and an expected output string and you no longer need Tk at all. Less is more when aiming for "minimal".

Answer (score 1):

How about building a find and replace dictionary that you can maintain.

```
def replace_text(file_path, b1o, b1a, b1p, b1e):
    find_replace = {'B1O': b1o, 'B1A': b1a, 'B1P': b1p, 'B1E': b1e}
    document = document(file_path)
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        for to_find, to_replace in find_replace.items():
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(to_find, to_replace)
    return document
```

Comment: I started this way, but it's relatively slow to run a scan per item vs one scan total that looks for all four strings

Comment: Ya, that is a good point. I think it is clean, but perhaps not performant

Answer (score 1):

You dont need if statements. If the text is not there, nothing will be replaced, easy as this :-)

```
def replace_text(file_path, b1o, b1a, b1p, b1e):
    document = document(file_path)

    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        for source, target in zip(
            ["B10", "B1A", "B1P", "B1E"],
            [b1o, b1a, b1p, b1e]
        ):
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(source, target)
    return document
```